# Python Requests Max retries exceeded with URL for Firebase Database REST API

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Python program that sends a high volume of patch requests to the Firebase database REST API for my project, around 5-15k requests every 15 minutes. I first tried to send these simultaneously, putting each call into its own thread, and I got this error repeatedly:

> Exception occurred: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my-app.firebaseio.com',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /items/item-id/.json (Caused
>   by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
>   8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))

When I limit the amount of items so that only ~100 requests happen each interval, there are no problems. One thing I tried was to spread out the requests so they occur over a 60 second span every 15 minutes, but that still didn't work.

The function that gets passed to each thread looks like this:

```
def make_request(self, val):
        url = "https://my-project.firebaseio.com/items/" + self.item_id + "/.json"
        try:
            self.s.patch(url, json.dumps({"my-key": val}), headers=None, timeout=None)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception occurred: " + str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use Firebase-Admin for Python

- This is usually faster than REST API
- Can run multiple threads and update the database simultaneously

```
pip install firebase-admin
```

#### Download the Admin SDK as json

- To generate a private key file for your service account:

  - In the Firebase console, open Settings > Service Accounts.
  - Click Generate New Private Key, then confirm by clicking Generate Key.
  - Securely store the JSON file containing the key.
  - For more details checkout [Firebase admin sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)
  - Save the file as firebase-admin-key.json

## Sample Code

```py
#Firebase Imports
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate("/firebase-admin-key.json")


print("initilising firebase app")

#Initilising Database
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL' : 'https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com/'
})

# Initilising Database 2
app2 = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com/'
}, name='app2')


# Update Data from firebase
def update_data_firebase(path,data):
    ref=db.reference('items',app2).child(path)
    ref.set(data)
    print("Succesfully updated the data in firebase")

# Main Function
def main():
    data_to_update={"my-key": "value"}
    update_data_firebase("Updated",data_to_update)

#Main program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you ever tried to upgrade the pyOpenSSL library?

Otherwise, `pip install -U pyopenssl`